# Python is not saving .pyc files in filesystem

Tags: python, linux

I have a python application running in an embedded Linux system. I have realized that the python interpreter is not saving the compiled .pyc files in the filesystem for the imported modules by default.

How can I enable the interpreter to save it ? File system permission are right.

Comment: The interpreter does it automatically for all imported modules.  You may not have write permissions to the directories the .py files are in.

Comment: Why do you want it? `.pyc` file is created by python only when you import the script as a module

Comment: To be more clear, Python _only_ creates .pyc files for _imported modules_.  If you want to create a .pyc for a file you call directly from teh command line, use [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/py_compile.html); for a whole directory, use [compileall](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/compileall.html#module-compileall).  There is a command line interface for both modules; just do `python -m py_compile script_name`.

Comment: Edited the question to handle comments: It is not creating .pyc for imported modules, fs permissions are fine.

Comment: Using `compileall` or `py_compile` ahead-of-time is better practice for an embedded system anyhow -- means you aren't wasting runtime writing out `.py[co]` files!

Comment: Check the value of `sys.dont_write_bytecode`.  It's probably set to True, and you can change it to False.

Comment: See if you have the environment variable `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` set: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of places where this enabled-by-default behavior could be turned off.

- `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` could be set in the environment
- `sys.dont_write_bytecode` could be set through an out-of-band mechanism (ie. site-local initialization files, or a patched interpreter build).
- File permissions could fail to permit it. This need not be obvious! Anything from filesystem mount flags to SELinux tags could have this result. I'd suggest using `strace` or a similar tool (as available for your platform) to determine whether any *attempts* to create these files exist.

On an embedded system, it makes much more sense to make this an explicit step rather than runtime behavior: This ensures that performance is consistent (rather than having some runs take longer than others to execute). Use `py_compile` or `compileall` to explicitly run ahead-of-time.

Comment: That's the path I took: deploy pyc files pre generated on the host machine.
Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @fanl, if you're generating them on the host, be certain the host is using the same release of Python; otherwise, they won't be compatible and thus will be ignored.